# Multiple parse error: syntax error on PHP code?

Tags: php, html, database

Hi i am receiving errors on my code which is linked to a contact form whenever i press submit. the current one is " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /websitename/public_html/GloboGym/assets/includes/signup.inc.php on line 12" "

Can anyone help me as i have tried removing this unexpected ';' and even all code apart from the first 3 lines and still get an error.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {

        require 'connect_db.php';

        $username = $_POST['uid'];
        $email = $_POST['mail'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];
        $passwordRepeat = $_POST['pass-repeat'];

        if (empty($username) || (empty($email) || (empty($password) || (empty($passwordRepeat)) {
            header("Location: ../assets/signup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You're missing at least a `)` or two or three.

Comment: Using a good IDE/Editor with syntax highlighting and error checking will go a long way in helping you with these errors.

Comment: Count the `(` and then the `)` on the previous line.

Comment: been a long day...........

Answer (score -1):

You should close your if function and just write the empty functions like this:

```
if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)) {
    //execute if statement
}
```